# How can i generate a dictionary from a list and remove all whitespaces

Tags: python, bash

I have the following list of 'arp -a' command output which is continuous as long as devices in the network are detected.

```
['XX.1.60.XX                ether   XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX   C                     wlan0', 'XXX.168.42.XXX           ether   XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX   C                     usb0', 'XX.1.62.XXX              ether   XX:9f:db:72:61:XX   C                     wlan0', '']
```

I wish to generate a dictionary with the ip address as the key and hardware address as the value ie:

```
{ 'XX.1.60.XX': XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX, 'XXX.168.42.XXX': 'XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX'}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Should it be in python or bash?? what does dictionary mean?? Please provide more information...

Comment: Seems like you're removing more than just whitespace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` to cut your line into words

```
data = ['XX.1.60.XX                ether   XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX   C                     wlan0', 'XXX.168.42.XXX           ether   XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX   C                     usb0', 'XX.1.62.XXX              ether   XX:9f:db:72:61:XX   C                     wlan0', '']

result = {}
for line in data:
    try:
        ip, _, hardware, _, _ = line.split()
        result[ip] = hardware
    except ValueError:
        # bad line format
        pass

print(result)
# {'XX.1.60.XX': 'XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX', 'XXX.168.42.XXX': 'XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX', 'XX.1.62.XXX': 'XX:9f:db:72:61:XX'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary comprehension:

```
o = ['XX.1.60.XX                ether   XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX   C                     wlan0', 'XXX.168.42.XXX           ether   XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX   C                     usb0', 'XX.1.62.XXX              ether   XX:9f:db:72:61:XX   C                     wlan0', '']

o = {v[0]: v[2] for v in (v.split() for v in o) if len(v) >= 3}
print(o)
```

Prints:

```
{'XX.1.60.XX': 'XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX', 'XXX.168.42.XXX': 'XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX', 'XX.1.62.XXX': 'XX:9f:db:72:61:XX'}
```

Comment: It's better you `split` before once, rather than multiple splits as in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
out = {re.findall(r'X.*?(?= )',i)[0]: re.findall(r'X.*?(?= )',i)[1] for i in x if i!=''}
```

Yields:

```
{'XX.1.60.XX': 'XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX', 'XXX.168.42.XXX': 'XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX', 'XX.1.62.XXX': 'XX:9f:db:72:61:XX'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(re.findall(r'([\dX.]+)\s.*?([\dX:a-f]+)\s', line)[0] for line in data if line)
# {'XX.1.60.XX': 'XX:16:35:b2:c9:XX', 'XXX.168.42.XXX': 'XX:35:cd:e8:a5:XX', 'XX.1.62.XXX': 'XX:9f:db:72:61:XX'}
```